# Appium - running browser tests without clearing browser data

Tags: google-chrome, testing, selenium, automated-tests, appium

I'm testing a web application on Chrome, Android (real device, not emulator) using Appium. Whenever I launch a test, all browser data (bookmarks, history etc.) is deleted. Is there any way to stop this from happening?

I tried setting the **noReset** capability to **true**, but that didn't help.

Thank you in advance for any help

```
public static Uri testServerAddress = new Uri("http://127.0.01:4723/wd/hub"); // Appium is running locally
    public static TimeSpan INIT_TIMEOUT_SEC = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(180);

public void SetUpTest()
    {
        if (driver == null)
        {
            DesiredCapabilities testCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
            testCapabilities.SetCapability("browserName", "Chrome");
            testCapabilities.SetCapability("platformName", "Android");
            testCapabilities.SetCapability("deviceName", "S(Galaxy S5)");
            testCapabilities.SetCapability("noReset", true);

            AppUrl = "http://www.google.com/"; //for example
            driver = new RemoteWebDriver(testServerAddress, testCapabilities, INIT_TIMEOUT_SEC);                
            driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(new TimeSpan(0, 0, globalTimeoutInSec));
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(AppUrl);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you testing in mobile device?

Comment: Oh, yes, forgot to add: I'm testing on an Android phone (Galaxy S5)

Comment: can you please post code which you have done? share code with question?

Comment: Added the test setup code to the question

Comment: Looks ok but I think selenium always start new session so it clears everything.

Comment: Still you can try : capabilities.setCapability("fullReset", False)

Comment: tried that, didn't help either. Anyway, thanks for your replies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chromedriver always starts totally fresh, nothing is keeping.
There is option to  re-use the existent one (using desired capability androidUseRunningApp) but unfortunately Appium any way will kill it.

Please see more details in this [post](https://discuss.appium.io/t/saved-chrome-settings-not-being-kept-when-testing-with-appium/3457/4)

Comment: I don't think this answers the question, at least not my understanding of it. I have the same issue, given: I am using my personal Android phone to test/learn appium. I use chrome (personally) and save some bookmarks. When: I use my phone for an appium test, Then: it wipes out all of my personal bookmarks. So, is there a way to prevent this? Is there anything for chrome/android similar to firefox/linux profiles? then I could use a "test-profile" on android that wouldn't kill my personal data. thx